# Creating a custom menu in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm currently using the below code to create a custom menu called 'Team Admin' in Google sheets which allows a user to activate the function 'newSheet' when the menu item 'Add Agents' is clicked.

```
function onOpen() {
    var menu = [{
            name : "Add Agents",
            functionName : "newSheet"
        }
    ];
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("⚙️Team Admin", menu);
}
function newSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var templateSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("SheetNames")
        var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A1:A30").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
        if (copy) {
            Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
        } else {
            templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a second menu item called 'Reset Agents' within the same menu which will allow the below function to run but can't figure out how to edit it, can someone help please?

```
function deleteRedundantSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Admin":
     case "Template":
     case "Stats":
     case "Notes":
     case "SheetNames":
           break;
     default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
        
    }
  }
}
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H24:AL39').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H67:AL83').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H88:L104').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to list menu items and their function names like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .addMenu(
      '⚙️Team Admin',
      [
        {
          name: 'Add Agents',
          functionName: 'newSheet',
        },
        {
          name: 'Reset Agents',
          functionName: 'deleteRedundantSheets',
        },
      ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

managed to sort it by editing as per below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('⚙️ Team Admin ')
      .addItem('Add team members', 'menuItem1')
      .addItem('Reset tracker', 'menuItem2')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("SheetNames")
             var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A1:A30").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
        var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
        if (copy) {
            Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
        } else {
            templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
            ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
            ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
}

function menuItem2() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Admin":
     case "Template":
     case "Stats":
     case "Notes":
     case "SheetNames":
           break;
     default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
        
    
  }
}
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H24:AL39').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H67:AL83').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Admin'); sheet.getRange('H88:L104').clearContent(); sheet.clearNotes();
}}}
```